# Import error while running py.test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import, pytest, importerror

When I tried to run pytest I get an error, this is my project structure:

```
slots_tracker/
    README.md
    development.txt
    requirements.txt
    tasks.py
    venv/
    slots_tracker/
        __init__.py
        conf.py
        db.py
        expense.py
        server.py
        swagger.yml
        test_api.py
```

This is my test file:

```
from expense import create
from conf import PayMethods


def test_create_new_expense():
    response = create(dict(amount=200, desc='Random stuff',
                           pay_method=PayMethods.Visa.value))
# We got a success code
assert response[1] == 201
```

when I run pytest with:

```
pytest
```

I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'expense'
```

If I run pytest with:

```
python -m pytest
```

I don't get any error, also I can run my app with and don't get any import error:

```
python server.py
```

I also noties that if I remove the `__init__.py` file I can run pytest with only:

```
pytest
```

any iade on I can fix this? removing the `__init__.py` doesn't look like the  'right' solution becuase I'm building a package so it should have an `__init__.py` file.

I'm running on a Mac with Python 3.6.5 in a virtual env.

Comment: Add an empty `conftest.py` file in the `slots_tracker` project dir: `touch slots_tracker/conftest.py`. This will fix the `sys.path` issue. Second, if `slots_tracker` should be a package, then treat it like one - instead of `from expense import create` use `from slots_tracker.expense import create` etc.

Comment: Should the `conftest.py` file be in the parent `slots_tracker` folder (`slots_tracker`) or in the child folder (`slots_tracker\slots_tracker`). Also, I have changed all the imports from `from expense import create,` to `from slots_tracker.expense import create`, after that I can run my tests with no problems, but now when I try to run the server (this is a flask app), with `python server.py` I get an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slots_tracker'`

Comment: How do you start the server?

Comment: `python server.py` there I have the following code:
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)`

Comment: That's because you go into package to run the module. From the root dir, run `python slots_tracker/server.py` or even better, run directly `python -m slots_tracker.server`.

Comment: @hoefling I'm also using `connexion` and `swagger.yml` in order to define the API for the package, so I still keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slots_tracker'` error. If I remove it ( `swagger.yml`) I can run the app with no problems. You can see all of my code [here](https://github.com/shlomiLan/slots_tracker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute imports in your code and tests.

Change this:

```
from expense import create
from conf import PayMethods
```

to:

```
from slots_tracker.expense import create
from slots_tracker.conf import PayMethods
```

I've just tested it and it works.